# Make .slideToggle() push content upward

Tags: jquery

When I'm using slideToggle(), it automatically pushes content downward, but I'd like it so that it pushes content upwards instead.

Picture showing wanted behavior:

[image]

Code example: https://jsfiddle.net/sk8rr3qn/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
   first top
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid1<br/>mid1<br/>mid1
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid3<br/>mid3<br/>mid3
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid4<br/>mid4<br/>mid4<br/>mid4
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid5<br/>mid5<br/>mid5<br/>mid5<br/>mid5
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid6<br/>mid6<br/>mid6
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
   first bottom
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
   second top
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid1<br/>mid1<br/>mid1
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2<br/>mid2
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid3<br/>mid3<br/>mid3
  </div>
  <div class="mid">
   mid4<br/>mid4<br/>mid4<br/>mid4
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
   second bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 25%;
}

.top, .mid, .bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}

.mid {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.top, .mid').click(function(){
        if( $(this).next().next().is(':hidden') || $(this).next().next().hasClass('bottom') ) {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
        }
    });
});
```

(I know .next().next() twice is unnecessary).

When I open the next div, I want the bottom to stay in place and let the top get pushed off screen. The reason is that I don't want to keep scrolling as content is added, and that newly added content will stay roughly in the center of the screen. I know this is partly possible using some .scroll()-function after the content has been loaded, but I'd rather have the content be pushed as the content is toggled, rather than after.

Similarly, the top should be pulled down when the toggle is turned off.

tl;dr: Let the bottom div be 'fixed' when using .slideToggle()

Answer (score 1):

I had similar task - list of DIVs, inside of every div we have "more details" button, and after click on it it shows hidden content and scroll it to the top of parent div.

I also use this nice plugin http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ there is many useful methods.

```
function details_opener() {
  if($(this).hasClass('closen')) {
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown(150, function(){
      $(this).parents('.mCustomScrollbar').mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo',$(this).parent());
    });
    $(this).removeClass('closen');
    $(this).children('.notice_text').show();
    $(this).children('.notice_text_short').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('closen');
    $(this).children('.notice_text').hide();
    $(this).children('.notice_text_short').show();
    $(this).parent().next().slideUp(150);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please assign `$(this)` to a variable and reuse that. Using `$(this)` repeatedly will not minimise.

Comment: @GoneCoding, in my code it is used in pair with eventListener, thats why it works:
var noticers = $(".notice");
        for (var i=0;i<noticers.length;i++){
            noticers[i].addEventListener("click", details_opener);
        }
To use it as standalone function it needs variable, correct.

Comment: Which has nothing whatsoever to do with my comment. if you use a jQuery selector more than once, cache it in a variable. Then it can be minimised to a single character in a min.js file.

Comment: @GoneCoding thanks for your comment about minimizing, I didnt know that, great comment!

Comment: Will this push the content upwards as new content is slid into position? I'd like to see a demo if possible.

Comment: @FrankVel, here is temporary link to the project - http://trans.markline.agency/search/ and to see the results you need to click here - http://joxi.ru/YmEaePXiZlgXXm

Comment: Thanks. It is close, but I'd like it to scroll down the length of the content at the same time the content is loaded, not after the content is loaded, so everything above the loaded content is pushed upwards.

Comment: @FrankVel in my example scrolling is triggered after slideDown will finish its animation. If you will more it directly after slideDown, it should start scrolling animation before slideDown ends.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem. I'm not sure if there are better ways as it has some flaws, and could probably be improved upon.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.top, .mid').click(function(){
        if( $(this).next().next().is(':hidden') || $(this).next().next().hasClass('.bottom') ) {
            if ( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
                $(this).next().show();
                var h = ($(this).next().height());
                $(this).next().hide();
                $(this).next().slideDown(600, 'linear');
                $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + h
                    }, 600, 'linear');
            } else {
                var h = ($(this).next().height());
                $(this).next().slideUp(600, 'linear');
                $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - h
                    }, 600, 'linear');
            }
        }
    });
});
```